# Autenticar sin password laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, login, autenticación, qrcode

muchas gracias de antemano por contestar y tomarse el tiempo de leer mi consulta que paso a describir, tengo que autenticar un usuario mediante QR, lo que me obliga a no conocer su password ya que esta estará determinada por el código QR. ¿Como puedo autenticar mi usuario, solo con su username o email?, el acceso me funciona sin problema, ya que simplemente hago esto una vez que levanto la información de una simple consulta como sigue

```
$result=0;
if ($request->data) {
    $user = User::where('QRpassword',$request->data)->first();
    if ($user) {
        response()->json($user,'200');
    }else{
        $result=0;
    }
}
return $result;
```

Necesito autenticar mi usuario para luego usar:

```
Auth::user()->username o Auth::user()->status
```

Answer (score 3):

Propongo que lo hagas de está forma

**Paso 1**

Ve a: `tuproyecto/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php` donde eliminarás o comentarás la sección que corresponde dentro dle formulario a la sección donde se pide la contraseña:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**Paso 2**

Ve a la siguiente ruta: `tuproyecto/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` donde vamos a *anular* el comportamiento que tiene por defecto el método `login` y lo colocaremos así:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $usuario = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();

        auth::login($usuario);

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

Donde:

- Obtenemos lo que nos llega por medio del formulario del login y lo leemos por medio del objeto `$request`
- Hacemos la consulta al modelo `User` donde el email sea igual al valor que nos manda el usuario
- Usamos el helper `auth` a través del cual accedemos al método estático `login`<sup>1</sup> que ya se encuentra en el *trait* llamado `AuthenticatesUsers` al cual le pasamos como parámetro la propiedad que guarda el resultado de nuestra consulta; como puedes leer en la documentación de Laravel este método nos permite loguear una instancia de `user` *(te recomiendo leer mas al respecto en dicho enlace)*
- Finalmente hacemos un retorno a la página que se encuentra el dashboard y que será donde mostremos los valores del usuario logueado

**Importante**

> No olvides que deberás importar tanto la clase `Request` como la clase del modelo `User`

Del siguiente modo:

```
use App\User; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Finalmente en la vista del `dashboard.blade.php` puedes imprimir los datos del usuario que ha iniciado sesión del siguiente modo:

```
 {{ auth::user()->email }}
```

Con un resultado visual como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Métodos de autenticación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu guía y ejemplo me sirvió de mucho, estaba bloquiadisimo en algo tan simple. Mil gracias nuevamente